# Reference to member 'decor' cannot be resolved without a contextual type

Tags: firebase, swiftui, augmented-reality, realitykit

I have been following the tutorial on youtube by Reality School. This part is for the firebase store model for storing usdz models with thumbnails. I have got stuck at .decor it is saying " Reference to member 'decor' cannot be resolved without a contextual type"

I do not have any reference to .decor in any other part of the code. And I can't find anything about it. Can anyone give some pointers in the correct direction?

```
import Foundation

import FirebaseFirestore


class ModelsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var models: [Model] = []
    
    private let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    
    func fetchData() {
        db.collection("models").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("Firestore: No documents")
                return
            }
            self.models = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Model in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                
                let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let categoryText = data["category"] as? String ?? ""
                let category = ModelCategory(rawValue: categoryText) ?? .decor
                let scaleCompensation = data["scaleCompensation"] as? Double ?? 1.0
                
                return Model(name: name, category: category, scaleCompensation: Float(scaleCompensation))
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is also the model code.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import Combine

 enum ModelCategory: String, CaseIterable {
    
    case porches
    case gazebos
    case pergolas
    case garages
    case roomabove
    case loftedroomabove
    
    
    var lable: String {
        get {
            switch self {
                
            case .porches:
                return "Porches"
            case .gazebos:
                return "Gazebos"
            case . pergolas:
                return "Pergolas"
            case .garages:
                return "Garages"
            case .roomabove:
                return "Room Above"
            case .loftedroomabove:
                return "Lofted Room Above"
                
               
            }
        }
    }
}

class Model: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var category: ModelCategory
  @Published var thumbnail: UIImage
    var modelEntity: ModelEntity?
    var scaleCompensation: Float
    
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init(name: String, category: ModelCategory, scaleCompensation: Float = 1.0) {
        
    self.name = name
        self.category = category
        self.thumbnail = UIImage(systemName: "photo")!
        self.scaleCompensation = scaleCompensation
  
        FirebaseStorageHelper.asyncDownloadToFilesystem(relativePath: "thumbnails/\(self.name).png") { localUrl in
            do {
                let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: localUrl)
                self.thumbnail = UIImage(data: imageData) ?? self.thumbnail
            } catch {
                print("Error loading image: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        
        
        
}
    
  //async model loading
    
    func asyncLoadModelEntity() {
        
        let filename = self.name + ".usdz"
       
        self.cancellable = ModelEntity.loadModelAsync(named: filename)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { loadCompletion in
                
                switch loadCompletion {
                case .failure(let error): print("Unable to load modelEntity for \(filename) Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                case .finished:
                    break
                }
                
            },  receiveValue: { modelEntity in
        
                self.modelEntity = modelEntity
                self.modelEntity?.scale *= self.scaleCompensation
        
                print("modelEntity for \(self.name) has been loaded")
        
                  })
    }
    
   
}
```

Comment: `decor` isn't in your `enum`

Comment: thank you! your a legend!!